# Github - remove issues entered in error

Tags: github, github-api

Dozens of issues have been entered into my project on github that have no place there.  Some Einstein ran a script and created all these nonsensical issues through the api.  Nothing is linked to these issues.

Surely there is someway I can delete them, but I can't seem to find it in the docs.

Comment: Any reason you don't just want to close them?

Comment: I'm guessing he wants to remove them so he can re-enter them so they are linked.  And as far as I can tell, all you can do is close the issues.  I can't find a way to actually remove-remove them.

Comment: I could do that but then it would say I have 200 closed issues when there is really only 100 and it looks like a disaster with all the nonsensical titles...

Comment: possible duplicate of [removing github issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081521/removing-github-issues)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to actually delete the issues. What you can do, to indicate that this was a spam attack, is create a new label. You can then use the API to [edit](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#edit-an-issue) each issue to be closed and labeled with the `SPAM` label. Those who look at it will see the label displayed along side the issue and it's really the best you can hope for.

If you're more comfortable with a specific language, check for a [library](http://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/) written in it to make your life easier too.

Comment: This is what I thought/feared.  Thanks everybody.

Comment: You can also [block the user](https://help.github.com/articles/blocking-a-user) to prevent him/her from opening any other issues on your repositories.

Answer (score 10):

Since Nov. 2018 and [this tweet](https://twitter.com/github/status/1060233780114288640)... you now can delete issues (if you are an Administrator/owner of a GitHub project)

The tweet read:

> You've been asking for it.
>
> You know the issue(s).
>
> Delete 'em.

[image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Dra0v6nVYAA-MuE.jpg]

Warning: there is no "Undo" for now.

This is [in public beta](https://blog.github.com/changelog/2018-11-07-delete-an-issue/) and the **[documentation is "Deleting an issue"](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-an-issue/)**

> When you delete an issue, collaborators do not receive a notification. If you visit the URL of a deleted issue, you'll see a message that says the issue was deleted.
>
> By default, you can only delete issues in a repository owned by your user account. As a collaborator in a repository owned by an individual user account, you cannot delete issues.

Answer (score 0):

Due to legal problems I've had to delete several issues with many comments of a project. I did as follows:

1. Deleting all comments
2. Editing the text of the issue ("THIS ISSUE WAS DELETED AND BLOCKED")
3. Blocking the issue

---

Copy paste on browser address bar:

```
javascript:(function(){ $('.delete-button.octicon.octicon-x.js-comment-delete').each(function(){ href=$(this).attr("href"); if(href!==undefined) { console.log("DELETING: "+href); $.ajax({type:"DELETE",url:href}); } }); firstCommentToedit=$('form.js-comment-update')[0]; $.ajax({ type:"POST", url:firstCommentToedit.action, data:{ _method:$(firstCommentToedit).find('input[name=_method]').val(), "issue[body]":"THIS ISSUE WAS DELETED AND BLOCKED", authenticity_token:$(firstCommentToedit).find('input[name=authenticity_token]').val() } }); lockLink=$('a[href$="/lock"]')[0]; if (lockLink!==undefined) { $.ajax({ type:"POST", url:lockLink.href, data:{_method:$(lockLink).attr("data-method")} }); } setTimeout(function(){window.location=window.location;},3000) })()
```

Expanded:

```js
javascript: (function() {
    $('.delete-button.octicon.octicon-x.js-comment-delete').each(function() {
        href = $(this).attr("href");
        if (href !== undefined) {
            console.log("DELETING: " + href);
            $.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",
                url: href
            });
        }
    });
    firstCommentToedit = $('form.js-comment-update')[0];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: firstCommentToedit.action,
        data: {
            _method: $(firstCommentToedit).find('input[name=_method]').val(),
            "issue[body]": "THIS ISSUE WAS DELETED AND BLOCKED",
            authenticity_token: $(firstCommentToedit).find('input[name=authenticity_token]').val()
        }
    });
    lockLink = $('a[href$="/lock"]')[0];
    if (lockLink !== undefined) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: lockLink.href,
            data: {
                _method: $(lockLink).attr("data-method")
            }
        });
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = window.location;
    }, 3000)
})()
```

Comment: What does item #3 do?

Comment: @Gaia I edited the answer. 
The code was a "shortcut" to automatically do the steps described above. I do not know if it still works (it depends on whether GitHub has changed class names).

Comment: Example: issue "deleted" with this method:  https://github.com/aabilio/PyDownTV2/issues/135