# Delete an issue on GitHub

Tags: github

Is it possible to delete an issue on GitHub?

I have a personal repo and created an incorret issue. Now, I wanna delete this, but I don't found anything about this.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/53195537/6309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official guide](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-an-issue/):

> 1. Navigate to the issue you want to delete.
> 2. On the
>      right side bar, under "Notificatons", click **Delete this
>      issue**.
> 3. To confirm deletion, click **Delete this
>      issue**.

[image]

---

If it does not work for some reason, there is another beta feature [to transfer an issue to another repository](https://help.github.com/articles/transferring-an-issue-to-another-repository/). (The button is right above the "Delete this issue" button)

1. Open a temporary repository (that you will delete in the end)
   [image]
2. Go to the issue that you would like to delete and click on **Transfer this issue** (or ask the repo owner to do it).
3. Delete the throwaway repo where the issue was transferred. Or not.

Comment: Ignore this comment I found the duplicate answer. `:-)`

Comment: GitHub release this feature in this week! Thanks anyways!