# Is linking to a GitHub issue reliable?

Tags: github

Is there any documentation out there to suggest that [GitHub](https://github.com/) issues are eternal? More specifically, are their URIs reliable to link to?

E.g., I want to link to a [Joda-Time issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda/issues/46) in a Javadoc to give context as to why a custom de/serializer was necessary. If the link is reliably static I'll be comfortable referencing it in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes

Git issues are completly reliable, no one can [remove an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081521/removing-github-issues?rq=1), even repository's administrators.

A git issue will never die, the worst thing that can happen to an issue is getting **locked**, resulting in others not being able to comment on them, but still, it's visible to everyone.

Edit: Please note that by removing a repository, all it's issues, pull requests, wiki pages, etc. are removed. More about [forks](https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility) on this.

Comment: Does that apply if the repository is deleted?

Comment: @SamB. No, once a repository is removed, all it's issues, pull requests, wiki, etc. are removed.